# Text formating default for function calls in visual studio

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2013

I would like to write function calls like so:

```
glUniformMatrix4fv(
    GetUniform("modelToCameraMatrix"),
    1,
    GL_FALSE,
    glm::value_ptr(model_matrix_)
);
```

Right now when I try to do this, when my text editor (vs2013) auto formats, it defaults these calls to something like this:

```
glUniformMatrix4fv(
    GetUniform("modelToCameraMatrix"),
    1,
    GL_FALSE,
    glm::value_ptr(model_matrix_)
    );
```

Any idea how to change this? I'm losing my hair over this trivial matter

Comment: look into Tools\Options\Text Editor\<language>\Formatting\... ?

Comment: @Chin Only thing I can think of is to turn off the option "Automatically format block when I type a }" I don't necessarily want that, but it is the lesser of two evils for me.

Comment: Visual Studio is a very solid IDE, and it has powerful compiling and debugging tools, but its lack of flexibility, customization, and refactoring are the reasons I have stopped using it for C++ development and have switched to a different IDE.

Comment: @AtlasC1 Yeah.. I do most of my stuff in sublime, but when I'm debugging I find it nice to just to muck around in the VS environment. I'm thinking there has to be a plug-in or something for this- hopefully anyway!

Comment: I can relate to your "trivial" matter. Much worse, I hate the way many programmers align { braces } so you can't easily eye up the code block. In my world, the `{` and the `code` and the `}` should all be aligned vertically, as the braces are a part of that code block.

Comment: I've not used VS2013 yet but as far as I know, as of VS 2012, this IDE is designed primarily for C# and VB; especially for C#. C/C++ come as complementary. So in essence, text formatting is aimed for C# & VB.

Comment: [Does this help at all?](http://edglogowski.azurewebsites.net/?p=10841)

Comment: I could recommend you Dev C++ and if you want i can say you how to do this!

Comment: @Rizier123 I would prefer to keep using VS

Comment: I use ClangFormat - A plugin for visual studio to do code formatting using the clang code tools. It's not "actively" processed though so you have to run it explicitly.

Comment: @MorphingDragon Thats close, but it'd be nice to get something that actively formats it like this.

Comment: @Calpratt there simply isn't any real time formatting plugins, AFAIK Microsoft doesn't expose any way for such a thing to exist. The closest you can get is "on-save". http://www.codemaid.net/

Comment: @MorphingDragon Aww, I guess I'm just a dreamer! I'll give  codemaid or ClangFormat a try tonight!